# How to convert System.Windows.Media.DrawingImage into Stream?

Tags: wpf, bitmap, memorystream

I'am trying convert DrawingImage into MemoryStream. My code looks like this:

```
public MemoryStream ImageStream(DrawingImage drawingImage)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        ImageSource imageSource = drawingImage;
        if (imageSource != null)
        {
            BitmapSource bitmap = imageSource as BitmapSource;
            if (bitmap != null)
            {
                BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));
                encoder.Save(stream);
            }     
        }

        return stream;
    }
```

But problem is after casting ImageSource into BitmapSource bitmap is always null. Any sugestion how to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your `bitmap` variable is always null is because `DrawingImage` does not extend `BitmapImage` or vice-versa, so the cast is guaranteed to fail. A `DrawingImage` does not contain any pixel data of any kind. It references a `Drawing` that is used whenever the image needs to be rasterized.

How did you find yourself in a situation where you want to rasterize a `DrawingImage` and serialize it into a stream? I get the feeling you are going about something in an unusual way if you have need of a function like this.

Nevertheless, you could implement this function by drawing the `DrawingImage` to a `DrawingVisual`, rendering it to a `RenderTargetBitmap`, and then passing the render target to the encoder to serialize the raster data to a stream.

```
public MemoryStream ImageStream(DrawingImage drawingImage)
{
    DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (DrawingContext dc = visual.RenderOpen())
    {
        dc.DrawDrawing(drawingImage.Drawing);
        dc.Close();
    }
    RenderTargetBitmap target = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)visual.Drawing.Bounds.Right, (int)visual.Drawing.Bounds.Bottom, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    target.Render(visual);

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(target));
    encoder.Save(stream);

    return stream;
}
```

If you want something a little more generic, I would split this into two methods and change some of the types.

```
public BitmapSource Rasterize(Drawing drawing)
{
    DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (DrawingContext dc = visual.RenderOpen())
    {
        dc.DrawDrawing(drawing);
        dc.Close();
    }
    RenderTargetBitmap target = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)drawing.Bounds.Right, (int)drawing.Bounds.Bottom, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    target.Render(visual);

    return target;
}

public void SavePng(BitmapSource source, Stream target)
{
    BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(source));
    encoder.Save(target);
}
```

Then you could use it with any kind of stream. For example, to save the drawing to a file:

```
using (FileStream file = File.Create("somepath.png"))
{
    SavePng(Rasterize(drawingImage.Drawing), file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a reply! I have a multithread application, and "DrawingImage" I am creating on second thread. Than I need to pass that "DrawImage" into UI thread, and display in Image control. Problem is I am receiving error "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it" when I'am using Dispatcher.Invoke to display "DrawImage" in Image control. Thats why i was thinking about convert "DrawImage" into stream, and than pass that stream to main thread and display. Now I'am going to try Your proposition.

Comment: You should be able to accomplish what you want with less steps and better performance. `DrawingImage` is a `Freezable`. If you call `Freeze()` on it, you should then be able to read it from another thread. If you also want to modify it on the other thread, then you can `Clone()` it from that thread.